# Prove that any linear functional on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$ with the Euclidean norm is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm not sure how to prove this without just using the fact that is equivalent to say that a linear functional is continous.

Comment: Linear functional from what real linear space to $\;\Bbb R\;$ ? From $\;\Bbb R\;$ to itself?:

Comment: Sorry I meant on $\mathbb{R^{n}}$

Comment: Assuming you are referring to $f:\Bbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$. By Riesz representation theorem it would be of the form $f(x)=a \cdot x$ for some vector $a$.

Comment: @AnuragA Thanks

Comment: @AnuragA I think you may have wanted to mean "for some **scalar** $\;a\in\Bbb R\;$ ..."

Comment: @DonAntonio correct me if I am mistaken but RRT guarantees the existence of such a vector. In fact, one doesn’t have to use the full strength of RRT to get that $f(\bf{x})=\langle \bf{a}, \bf{x} \rangle$.

Comment: @AnuragA I think you may have meant that $\;a\cdot x\;$ is the *dot product* between two vectors. It is just fine, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For

$\vec v \in \Bbb R^n, \tag 1$

we may write

$\vec v = \displaystyle \sum_1^n v_i \vec e_i, \tag 2$

where $\vec e_i$, $1 \le i \le n$ is a basis of $\Bbb R^n$, orthonormal in the Euclidean inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_2$ on $\Bbb R^n$, which defines the Euclidean norm norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2 = \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle^{1/2}$ on $\Bbb R^n$ (see note below); then with

$\phi: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R \tag 3$

linear, we have

$\phi(\vec v) = \phi \left (\displaystyle \sum_1^n v_i \vec e_i \right ) = \displaystyle \sum_1^n v_i \phi(\vec e_i); \tag 4$

thus

$\vert \phi(\vec v) \vert = \left \vert \displaystyle \sum_1^n v_i \phi(\vec e_i) \right \vert \le \displaystyle \sum_1^n \vert v_i \phi(\vec e_i) \vert =  \sum_1^n \vert v_i \vert \vert \phi(\vec e_i) \vert; \tag 5$

let

$M = \max \{\vert \phi(\vec e_i) \vert, \; 1 \le i \le n \}; \tag 6$

then

$\vert \phi(\vec v) \vert \le \displaystyle \sum_1^n \vert v_i \vert \vert \phi(\vec e_i) \vert \le M \sum_1^n \vert v_i \vert; \tag 7$

also,

$\vert v_i \vert \le \sqrt { \displaystyle \sum_1^n v_i^2 }, \ 1 \le i \le n; \tag 8$

whence

$\displaystyle \sum_1^n \vert v_i \vert \le n \sqrt { \displaystyle \sum_1^n v_i^2 }, \tag 9$

so that (7) becomes

$\vert \phi(\vec v) \vert \le M n \sqrt { \displaystyle \sum_1^n v_i^2 } = Mn\Vert \vec v \Vert_2, \tag {10}$

which shows that $\phi$ is bounded in the Euclidean norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ on $\Bbb R^n$, with bound $Mn$.

***Nota Bene:***  The definition of Euclidean norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert_2$ on $\Bbb R^n$ used here is the usual one defined in terms of the Euclidean inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_2$, where if

$\vec w = \displaystyle \sum_1^n w_i \vec e_i, \tag{11}$

we have

$\langle \vec v, \vec w \rangle_2 = \displaystyle \sum_1^n v_i w_i, \tag{12}$

from which

$\Vert \vec v \Vert_2 = \sqrt{\langle \vec v, \vec v \rangle_2} = \sqrt {\displaystyle \sum_1^n v_i^2}; \tag{13}$

the vectors $\vec e_i$ are chosen orthonormal with respect to this basis:

$\langle \vec e_i, \vec e_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}, \; 1 \le i, j \le n. \tag{14}$

***End of Note.***